# how to design messages in a java client-server model

Tags: java, serialization, client, messaging

i have set up a basic client and a basic server using java sockets. it can successfully send strings between them.

now i want to design some basic messages. 
could you give me any recommendations on how to lay them out?
should i use java's serialzation to send classes?
or should i just encode the information i need in a custom string and decode on the other side?

what about recognizing the type of messages? is there some convention for this? like the first 4 characters of each message are a identifier for the message?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you not to reinvent the wheel. If java serialization suits you, just use it.

Also take into account that there are some nice serialization frameworks around:

[thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/), from facebook, and  [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) from Google.

Thrift also is a RPC mechanism, so you could also use it instead of opening / reading raw sockets, but this, of course, depends on your problem domain.

Edit: And answering your question about the message formatting. Definitely if you want to implement your own protocol and if you have more than one type of messages you should implement a header yes. But I warn you that implementing a protocol is hard and very error prone. Just create an object containing the different inner objects + methods you need, if you want add it a *version* field and make it implement the java.io.Serializable interface.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe JMS would help you, it's hard to say without knowing the details.  But JMS is standard, well thought out and versatile, and there are an impressive number of implementations available, open source and commercial.  We use Sun's [OpenMQ](https://mq.dev.java.net/) implementation and we're quite happy with it.  It's fast enough for our needs, very mature and reliable.
Mind you, JMS is not a lightweight affair by any standard so it may very well be overkill for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to deploy this in a production environment, I'd advice you to look at either [RMI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/rmi/) or [XML web services](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/). (Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) are interesting too, but do not include a standard protocol for message transport, although [3rd party implementations](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns#RPC_Implementations) exist.)

If you're doing this for the pleasure of learning, there are tons of ways to go about this. In general, a message in a generic messaging system will have some kind of "envelope format" which contains not only the message body, but also metadata about the message. A bare minimum for the header is something that identifies the intended receiver - either an integer identifier, a string representing a method name or a file, or something like it.

A simple example is [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), a plain-text format where the envelope and the is made up of all the lines until the first blank line. The first line identifies the protocol version and the intended receiver (≈the file requested), the following lines are metadata about the request, and the message body follows the first blank line.

In general, XML is a common format for distributed services (mostly because of its good schema capabilities and cross-platform support), although some schemes use other formats for simplicity and/or performance. RMI uses standard Java object serialization, for example.

What you choose to use is ultimately based on your needs. If you want to make it easy to interact with your system from a large amount of platforms, use XML web services (or [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)). For communication between distributed Java subsystems, use RMI.  If your system is *extremely* transaction intensive, maybe a custom binary format is best for faster processing and smaller messages - but before doing this "optimization", remember that it requires a *lot* more work to get it working properly and that most apps won't benefit a lot from it.